Debug session with breakpoint halts clutters editor window with extra source files
Is there a possibility to let automatically remove those debug session related files when I return to the default perspective (from the debug perspective)?
The current behaviour let some source files (which are part of my coding focus) move under the "show list" button.

In such a case, I right-click on the tab of the most recently used editor I want to keep and choose Close Tabs to the Right. If this is not enough, you might use Eclipse Mylyn. Be also aware of the preference General > Appearance: Show most recently used tabs.

Also make sure the main Run/Debug preference page still has Reuse editor when displaying source code selected. That allows it to reuse opened editors whose contents haven't been dirtied as you step from file to file.

After doing some experiments, Mylyn looks quite interesting, but it seems to lack a feature to freeze the context state. Without anything like that, the context is extended during debugging sessions (also when change monitoring is unticked). BTW: I just found an old posting of mine: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/717431/#msg_717431
Currently, I acknowledge that 'close tabs to the right' is a workable solution.
Note: the two mentioned preferences (thanks!) were already set active.
